# C++ private static member variables

Tags: c++, linker-errors, static-methods, static-members

This C++ code is producing linker errors at compile time:

```
// A.h
class A {
    public:
        static void f();
    private:
        static std::vector<int> v;
};

// A.cpp
void A::f() {
    // this line is causing trouble
    int i = v.size();
}
```

Moving the vector declaration into the cpp file works. However I want to understand the linker error `"Undefined symbols"` cause in the above code. What is causing the linker error in the above code?

Comment: You're missing a definition for `v` in `A.cpp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static members have to be defined in a compilation unit:

```
// A.cpp

vector<int> A::v;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// A.h
class A {
    public:
        static void f();
    private:
        static std::vector<int> v;
};

// A.cpp
//modify add this line
static std::vector<int> A::v;
void A::f() {
    // this line is causing trouble
    int i = v.size();
}
```